# Android studio 1.3 unable to get entire tests to run

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

In android studio 1.3 i'm not able to run the entire test cases. I can run individual test cases without any issue but when i try to run all tests i get the following error:

```
  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the 
UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Test worker" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I tried to increase my memory from the shell and also from android studio but its not helping at all.

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m
```

my tests are all mocked( i have a flavor called mocked) so i switch to the build variant mockDebug and then i run the following on terminal:

```
./gradlew :app:TestMockDebug
```

My tests are using robolectric as the test runner.

The other funny thing is if i go from the project explorer and right click ont he package containing the tests and do a "run tests in package ..." then it runs the tests. So my only problem is getting it to run from command line.

Comment: I recently also faced with this issue. I went through me test and added a lot of teardown methods where I do `reset()` for my spies instances. It helped for a bit but I getting this exception time to time. There is todo on my list to completely rework some test to remove spies and reduce mocks as much as possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To resolve this out of memory exception i added more memory by setting shell environment variables as follows:

```
    export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m"
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m"
```

Even though i had memory set in gradle.properties it looks like from the command line those properties are not seen. So the command line java options have to be set to increase the memory.  if you check the terminal logs after doing this you'll see a line like this proving the same:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m
```